# How to delete registry key for specific user?

Tags: c#

I have two users: SuperUser and MyUser. How can I delete some registry key for MyUser when I am logged in as SuperUser.

In my C# application I want to delete key by path: MyUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyApp.
Note I am runnnig my C# application when I am logged as SuperUser.

It seems that Microsoft.Win32.Registry class doesn't have a possibility to do that.

Comment: Can you post the code that deletes the registry key?

Comment: afaik this is not possible. The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` tree is stored in the `ntuser.dat` file for each user and loaded only on logon. I once made a very dirty hack like loading this `ntuser.dat` into the registry, changing it and exporting it back. But that is really dirty and actually leaves zombies in the registry.

Comment: @RenéVogt You can pull this off, but you've got to get the user profile loaded into HKEY_USERS first.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling when we did this we were running with admin rights but did not know the passwords of the users, so we could not use `LogonUser` and `LoadUserProfile`. As I said, it was a dirty hack I'm not so proud of.

Answer (score 1):

The profile may or may not be loaded. In order to ensure that it is loaded, you'll need to logon the user. Then you can load the profile and make changes. You'll need to pinvoke `LogonUser()` and `LoadUserProfile()`.

```
// log on user
UserToken usertoken = null;
LogonUser(user, domain, pass, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, 
              LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out usertoken));

// load the profile
PROFILEINFO p = new PROFILEINFO();
p.dwFlags = 1;
p.lpUserName = user;
p.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(p);
LoadUserProfile(usertoken, ref profile);

// get a handle to the registry
Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle saferh = 
   new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle(profile.hProfile, false);

Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = 
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.FromHandle(m_RegHandle, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Default);
```